# LDS vs the @wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, lds

I'm new to LWC and learning about LDS(lightning Data Service) and @wire adaptor. I'm totally confused in them. Can anyone please explain what is what and when to use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lightning Data Service (LDS)** is the service that provides data access and a coherent record cache to Lightning components (both Aura and LWC). It can create, update, and delete records, and is used in any standard library component that does any CRUD operations in Salesforce, including `lightning:recordEditForm` / `lightning-record-edit-form`, `force:recordData`, `getRecord`, etc. You do not directly use LDS, but instead call it through one of the various methods just mentioned (and others in the documentation).

The **wire service** is a streaming object interface that provisions data from any API it is linked to. Inside of Salesforce, only standard library components can be used with the wire service, but in LWC OSS (Open Source Software), this service can be wired up to any API, such as AWS, Heroku, Salesforce, or whatever else you want to use it for. The wire service automatically triggers new render cycles when the data changes, supports reactive variables for parameters, and automatically calls the attached wire handler, if defined.

So, when you want to load a record, metadata, etc, you use a wire method with a library component that's backed by LDS. When you want to create or edit a record, you use LDS-backed components, such as `lightning-record-edit-form` or `force:recordData`. When you use LWC OSS, you use the wire service to automatically provision data from an API. You cannot use LDS outside of Salesforce, and you cannot use custom APIs with the wire service inside of Salesforce (at least, not directly; you can call an API through Apex in Salesforce).

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox for the answer.but unfortunately i am not allowed to upvote yout answer due to my less reputation points :(

Comment: @mdanish9 You can still use the ✔ to accept the answer, if you want to. This will also give you bonus reputation that'll help get you more privileges in the future.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox